# For which $z_1$, $z_2$ is it true that $-i\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2} = \arcsin(z)\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}$?

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

$\operatorname{Log}$ denotes the principal branch of the complex log

I want to know for which $z_1$, $z_2$ it is true that $$-i\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2} = \arcsin(z)\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}$$ $\tag1$

I don't think it warrants asking a second question separately but I also want to know for which $z_1$, $z_2$ it is true that

$$-i\sinh^{3}(\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}))\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}=(1-z^2)^{3/2}\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}$$ $\tag2$

Lastly, I want to know for which $z_1$, $z_2$ it is true that
$$\frac{i}{4}\sinh(4\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1}))\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}=z(2z^2-1)\sqrt{1-z^2}\Big|_{z_1}^{z_2}$$ $\tag3$

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=-i%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C2%5D%2BSqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29-ln%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C3%5D%2BSqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=arcsin%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29-arcsin%5C%2840%29Divide%5Bi%2C3%5D%5C%2841%29) with this numerical example we see that the sign is wrong on (1)

[Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=-%5C%2840%29%5C%2840%29ln%5C%2840%293%2BSqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%293%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29-ln%5C%2840%292%2BSqrt%5BPower%5B%5C%2840%292%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D-1%5D%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29%5C%2841%29Sqrt%5B-1%5D) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=arcsin%5C%2840%293%5C%2841%29-arcsin%5C%2840%292%5C%2841%29) with this numerical example we see that the sign is not wrong on (1)

This gives me the impression that (1) is always true up to a minus sign.

My reason for thinking that (1) is nearly true in the first place is that $$\frac{d}{dz}(-i\operatorname{Log}(z+\sqrt{z^2-1})) = \frac{d}{dz}\arcsin(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$ $\tag4$

I have similar reasons for thinking that the other two are nearly true as well.